# Cannot use imported Wav files from AudioShare with the Superpowered Engine

Tags: ios, audio, wav, superpowered

I am working on updates to an iOS app which uses the advanced audio player in the Superpowered audio engine; we use the audio engine for the real-time audio effects when playing back audio.

It works great but we have an issue; we are adding support to import audio using the AudioShare app.  The default format in Audioshare is to use WAV files.

http://kymatica.com/Software/AudioShare

https://github.com/lijon/AudioShareSDK

For some reason, the Superpowered audio engine does not like these WAV files.  These files are playable with the audio players in AV foundation.

It is possible to transcode the audio to work with the Superpowered engine using AV Foundation - I would like to avoid that. From a user experience perspective, it slows things down having to do a transcode. And of course, Audioshare lets you convert files to other commons audio formats.   So it is not a blocker but it is a feature that we would like to work more seamlessly.

Is there anything I can do to diagnose the issue further in the Superpowered engine?

Comment: Upload a sample WAV file produced by Audioshare please, so I can investigate what really is inside. A WAV can hold many different things, not just uncompressed audio.

Comment: Hi Gabor.  Thanks for the assist.  Here is an audio file created in Audioshare with the default WAV file settings.  Yes, I totally know what you mean about WAV files as a container.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7jmdrhipxg7nif/Recorded%20Audio.wav?dl=0

Comment: I can play the attached file without any problems with the current version of Superpowered.

Comment: Hello Gabor.  Thanks for the assist.  I will review my code;  I had also recently updated the project to use the latest version of the SDK.

Comment: During the import process, I open the file using the Superpowerd decoder class as way to check if the file is file audio.  The decoder is failing to open WAV files but will open M4A audio files for example.  What is best way to check if a file is valid for playback in iOS with Superpowered?

Comment: This is getting more complicated - ha ha.  It seems AudioShare's Wav file are not all the same.  A WAV file of a recording made with Audio Share works but a WAV file of an existing music file does not work.  I can share files but I don't want to be uploading copyrighted music to Drop Box.  I will find something in public domain to test with.

Comment: Yes, a successful SuperpoweredDecoder open() is a good way to check if the audio is valid for playback with Superpowered. Please find a way to send me a WAV file which can not be played with Superpowered.

Comment: Here is a click track that was imported into AudioShare & then converted to a WAV file in AudioShare.  The file does open with apps like Audacity but when trying to use in the iOS app - error. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uu7lsb40jc06l0q/File%202017-10-02%2C%2010%2058%2009%20AM.wav?dl=0

Comment: Thank you for this file. This has 32-bit floating point PCM inside. I found a small bug in our implementation for this. The next Superpowered update will have the fix.

Comment: I think i'm having the same issue, was this resolved in Superpowered?

Comment: Yes.  It was fixed in a update to the superpowered SDK.

Comment: Was your format just 32bit float? Having the issue after converting pcm to .wav but the file plays else where :(